# Monerd error on rpc-bind to make a public node

Tags: monerod, full-node, rpc, monero-wallet-rpc

I set my **rpc-bind-ip=x.x.x.x** in my bitmonero.conf file and used my public IP addres. But I am getting this error:

> ERROR   default src/rpc/rpc_args.cpp:80 --rpc-bind-ip permits inbound
>   unencrypted external connections. Consider SSH tunnel or SSL proxy
>   instead. Override with --confirm-external-bind

What else do I need to do to make a public node where my monejuro can connect to?

FYI, I'm on linux with firewall enabled and ports opened for monero rpc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do what it's told and add --confirm-external-bind

Comment: This is correct but also you should consider the warning text. Ideally run through stunnel or over ssh.

Comment: Indeed. But m2049r was more precise in patoshi previous question, about including login and password. Btw I don't see an easy way to use a node through ssh tunnel with monerujo. That will imply bringing the tunnel up everytime before connecting, and might require a rooted phone (which is a security threat I would not recommand along with monerujo).

Comment: is that **confirm-external-bind=1** or true? no where does it say to use true or 1 when using it in bitmonero.conf file.

Comment: Both are correct.